# Eclipse with maven includes test classes in classpath of dependent projects

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a Maven multi-module project which is open in Eclipse. For simplicity's sake, let's say it contains two projects: common and app. Comm contains the class "Foo" and "FooTest".

When running the app project, "FooTest" is on the classpath.

Project layout is as follows

```
common
  src/main/java/.../Foo.java
  src/test/java/.../FooTest.java
app
```

The real problem is that this is using the Spring framework and the "app" project is trying to load a `@TestConfiguration` from the test packages.

I'm not sure what additional information to include, I will update this question with any information requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse does not have separate classpaths for test and main code, so this is the result.  To my understanding both Netbeans and IntelliJ do this correctly.

A possible solution would be to move the test code to a separate module.

Comment: It appears this will be fixed in 4.8 https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=224708

Comment: Great.  I was wondering if core Eclipse development had completely congealed.  Only took 10 years.

Comment: Eclipse is the worst. Falling behind everything.

Comment: But it is free which is a good selling point.  If you have the choice I would recommend learning both Netbeans and IntelliJ besides Eclipse.  They all have strengths and weaknesses.